# change color of textfield label in MUI

Tags: css, material-ui, jsx

Hi I am having trouble changing the color of the text label in a MUI text field. I've managed to customise the border colors, and hover states (including the label) - just not the label color when not in hover state. I've tried various class names (including MuiInputBase-input) I found in the DOM as I did with the others, but to no avail. I also tried inputProps, but doesn't do anything either. Here is my code

```
               <TextField 
                    className="w-full my-2 "
                    id="outlined-basic" 
                    label="Distance (miles)" 
                    inputProps={{ sx: {color: '#F1F4F9'} }} <- this doesn't do anything 
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => {setSearchParams({...searchParams, dist: e.target.value})} }
                    sx={{
                        // focused border color
                        "&& .Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {  
                            border: "1px solid #3B82F6",
                        },

                        // focussed label color
                        "&  .css-1sumxir-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
                            color: "#3B82F6",
                        },

                        // normal border color 
                        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {  
                            border: "1px solid #F1F4F9",
                        },
                        
                        // normal label color - <- DOESN'T DO ANYTHING
                        "& .MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
                            color: "#F1F4F9"
                        },
                    }}
                                         />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, this is one way you can change the label color:

```
    <TextField
      className="w-full my-2 "
      id="outlined-basic"
      label="Distance (miles)"
      InputLabelProps={{
        sx: { color: "red", "&.Mui-focused": { color: "green" } },
      }}
      variant="outlined"
    />
```

Some tips:

- Don't use/copy the generated classes from the DOM, because they can change!
  `.MuiFormLabel-root` **DO**
  `.css-1sumxir-MuiFormLabel-root` - **DON'T**
- Double ampersant is not valid syntax
  `& .MuiFormLabel-root` **DO**
  `&& .MuiFormLabel-root` **DON'T**